# How to position an element relative to window scroll position using CSS?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to position an element on screen based on the following formula:

```
element.style.top = element.pivot_y + window.scrollY;
```

I'm doing this using `JavaScript`, with `window.requestAnimationFrame`. The problem is that `requestAnimationFrame` is not available on certain browsers, so I have to fallback to a timer, **which makes my element wiggle** due to lack of synchronisation with rendering. This, can I position an element similarly, without invoking JavaScript?

Comment: CSS doesn't support math.

Comment: CSS doesn't work dynamically like that. You will need to find a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible.

Comment: @cale_b maybe I might rephrase that question, I want a CSS solution, not necessarily using a formula. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you this should be easily possible with `position: fixed;` and `top: pivot_y` where pivot_y has to be a fixed number

Comment: This lead to an unrelated problem with my application: elements that are child of a div, but that go outside that divs bounding rect, are still rendered even when that div has "overflow: hidden" property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `position: fixed;`.

**CSS**

```
.square {
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 30%;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dh22C/)